# Thunderbird asks for passwords after some time from setting up the accounts. Passwords expiration?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, gmail-imap, man-in-the-middle

When connecting email accounts to Thunderbird, I've checked `remember this password` option.
But after a few weeks of password reentering-free life, it asks for the passwords yet again, out of the blue.

Is this sort of expiration a normal thing and can I safely re-enter the passwords?
Or perhaps it is some form of Man-in-the-middle attack?

The accounts I've been asked to re-authenticate to are Gmail.
Other work just fine.

I'm using Ubuntu-ish OS, haven't changed a thing, haven't moved to a different location (IP change), haven't even unplugged my setup. The only change is installing updates on a daily basis.

Comment: Potentially relevant after Googling "Thunderbird gmail remember this password": https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1086835

Comment: So, yes, MitM: but it's Gmail

Comment: Thanks for the link. The clue is "_The token will expire at some point, so you'll have to renew it in the future._". If I got it right, [that](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) is the reference confirming this, along with expiration cause: "_The user account has exceeded a certain number of token requests._"

Comment: Do you want to convert it to an answer somehow, or should I do that?

Comment: If that's the case, this is actually off-topic here. I'll migrate to SuperUser and you should answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From June 2022, Google has reinforced its security. Fortunately it IS POSSIBLE TO CONTINUE using Mozilla Thunderbird with gmail! If someone pass by rejection of the password, you must:

1- Access your Google Acount Configuration via browser.

2- Activate "2 steps verification" that uses phone and sms to verify you

3- Create the new "App Password" that contains 16 characteres and are accepted to keep using Mozilla Thunderbird.
This larger password does not change your general password. It is only for the apps to connect in a secure way!

I have just did it and now Thunderbird is considered secure again by Google!

Copy this new App Password and when Thunderbird asks the password, remind to mark the checkbox "Save the password in the Account Manager" and paste the new App Password!